# Error while migrating from log4j to log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I want to migrate from **log4j** to **log4j2**. I have a custom logger class `MyLoggerImpl`which extends `Logger` from log4j and implements user defined interface.

**MyLoggerImpl.java (using log4j)**

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;    
public class MyLoggerImpl extends Logger implements MyLoggerInterface
{    
     private Logger logger = null;

     MyLoggerImpl(){};

     MyLoggerImpl(Class clas){
     logger = Logger.getLogger(clas);
   }
}
```

I tried modifying custom class as below. Also, configuration files like log4j2.xml etc are in place.

**Solution 1**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;    
public class MyLoggerImpl extends LogManager implements MyLoggerInterface
{

     private Logger logger = null;

     MyLoggerImpl(){};

     MyLoggerImpl(Class clas){
     logger = LogManager.getLogger(clas);
   }
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;    
public class MyLoggerImpl implements MyLoggerInterface
{

     private Logger logger = null;

     MyLoggerImpl(){};

     MyLoggerImpl(Class clas){
     logger = LogManager.getLogger(clas);
   }
}
```

However I am getting below exception

```
Reason:java.lang.ClasCastException: com.custom.logger.MyLoggerImpl incompatible with org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
```

I am not getting what is causing this. Please help.

**UPDATE 1**

```
public interface MyLoggerInterface{
    public void info(Object infoObject1);
    public void info(Object infoObject1, Object infoObject2);
    public void info(int scheduleId, Object infoObject1);
    public void info(int scheduleId, Object infoObject1, Object infoObject2);

    // similar variations for error and debug methods
}
```

Comment: include MyLoggerInterface please.

Comment: Could you show us `MyLoggerInterface`?

Comment: Please check **UPDATE 1**

Comment: @TechyGuy I think it's not good idea `MyLoggerInterface` because there are so many custom options for `log4j2` Could you tell me what do you want to do by using MyLoggerInterface?

Comment: @TechyGuy Anyway, current problem is crash state with `Logger` Interface and `MyLoggerInterface` Interface. `Logger` Interface implements at `AbstractLogger` Class but your `MyLoggerInterface` didn't implements any methods at `MyLoggerImpl` Class, so `JVM` returned `java.lang.ClassCastException`. If you want to know about `ClassCastException` then visit [this site](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classcastexception-arrays-arraylist)

Comment: @Han `MyLoggerImpl` implements all the methods from `MyLoggerInterface`. I did not mention them here to keep question abstract. Also, had it not implemented the methods, I would have got compilation error. But I am getting runtime exception

Comment: @TechyGuy Thanks. I didnt' know `ClassCastException` is compilation error. Anyway `LogManager.getLogger(clas)` will return `Logger` in `org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger` but you said you want to use `MyLoggerInterface`. In this case there are **two**  Logger `Logger.info()` and `MyLoggerInterface.info()`. so it is the cause of compilation error. How about use `log4j2`'s options?

Comment: @Han `ClassCastException` is NOT compile time, It is Runtime exception only. I meant if I didn't implement any method from interface, it will be reported at compilation. Also, are you suggesting not to use `MyLoggerInterface`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213177/discussion-between-han-and-techyguy).